# How do I simplify a LINQ query with multiple .Select() in order to return an IQueryable(int)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In the LINQ query below, I want to return the ContractorId found in the Contractors table. Not all people in the Contacts table are in the Contractors table. What I really want is a list of ContractorIds for those contractors meeting the criteria. ContractorId is not the same as ContactId.

```
var contractorsWithCertsFor2010 = dc.Contacts.Where(x => x.Contractors
.Any(d => d.ContractorStatus
.Any(date => date.StatusDate.Year >= 2010)))
.Select(x => x.Contractors
.Select(dr => dr.ContractorId)); 

IEnumerable<int> differenceQuery = allPeople.Except(contractorsWithCertsFor2010);
```

allPeople is a `IQueryable<Int>` but contractorsWithCertsFor2010 is a `IQueryable<IEnumerable<Int>>.` Something isn't right there. The multiple .Select()  is causing the `IQueryable<IEnumerable<Int>>` so I'm looking for a way to eliminate one of the .Select() and get a return of

```
IQueryable<Int>
```

Any Suggestions? Thanks!

Solution:
One solution is posted in a reply below. I created another solution prior to seeing that one. In my solution, I started out in the Contractors table instead of the Contacts table, eliminating one layer and one .Select() statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only want contractors that have contact record and since the only thing you selecting is the contractor id, you might want to try this:

```
var contractorsWithCertsFor2010 = dc.Contractors
    .Where(c => c.Contacts.Any() && c.ContractorStatus
        .Any(cs => cs.StatusDate.Year >= 2010))
    .Select(c => c.ContractorId);
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently using. I was over-thinking a rather simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

First thought: Try SelectMany to flatten your results. So, identical code except for:

```
//...
.SelectMany(x => x.Contractors
                  .Select(dr => dr.ContractorId)); 

IEnumerable<int> differenceQuery = allPeople.Except(contractorsWithCertsFor2010);
```

Comment: .SelectMany worked just fine, I just tested it. Prior to seeing your post, I went back and rewrote the query from scratch. I now have two working solutions. Again, I was over-thinking the solution and multiple .Select() were not necessary. Thanks!